# Is it necessary to do select command before update command in OracleDataClient

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle

I've recently started working in ASP.NET and RDBMS.I'm making a test form where I can do basic add,update,delete operations.I'm using OracleDataClient to do the DB operations.I was able to populate a listbox using OracleDataAdapter.
Now after clicking on update button,I intend to Update in DB.I've Dataadapter with it's update property.But the update query is not happening.The examples I saw over net all have Select command before Update.Is it actually like that or am I missing some point.
How does Oracle DataClient work with Insert,Update,Delete Commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep it in datalist or temporary table like data table or Hash table....display data in datalist and for update operation use (1)the proper query (2) command Behaviour (3) check the connection and  Dml command operation (4) CommandBehavior

Comment: I've done this but still something is wrong...which I can't figure out